# Headphone for recording voice for YouTube

Tags: youtube, audio-recording, microphone

I want to record my voice for YouTube videos. So should I get a headphone with mic like `Senheiser GSP 300` or a microphone separately and a monitor headphone..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quality of the headphones will only affect how the audio sounds to you, so you don't necessarily need to spend your money on that to improve the audio for a youtube video. I would suggest focussing your money on the mic itself.

[This is a great roundup of relatively inexpensive mics, with audio clips so you can hear how they sound.](https://marco.org/podcasting-microphones)

Gaming headsets tend to have relatively cheap mics in them, and you need to be really careful about the mic's position.  Too close and you get breath noise and popping sounds. Too far away and you get room noise and hissing on the audio.

Comment: Thanks @tomh...